# Lazily transpose dimensions 0 and 2 in iterator model

Tags: python, iterator

Given an iterable of an iterable of an iterable `it_it_it` (i.e. a lazy representation of 3d array) you can lazily transpose dimensions `0` and `1` by `zip(*it_it_it)` and dimensions `1` and `2` by `map(lambda it_it: zip(*it_it), it_it_it)`.

However, the last combination (`0` and `2`) is trickier. It seems you must full evaluate the outer two iterators before yielding anything and the type yielded must be `List[List]` not a lazy `Iterable[Iterable]`; the inner most iterator is the only one that can be lazily evaluated (i.e. `Iterable[List[List]]` is the best you can do).

I'm going to give an answer but am **interested in a more elegant answer**.

###### Aside:

I'm interested in this question for understanding the problem with statically typed iterators i.e. rust and c++. Do you make sure to set up your data so you never have to do this operation. Is the best thing to do is just fully evaluate the iterators to `List[List[List]]` and then transpose c style.

Comment: It sounds like you might think `zip(*it_it_it)` is lazier than it really is. It needs to fully exhaust the outer iterator before even calling `zip`. Similarly, the `map` thing fully exhausts each `it_it` before calling `zip`.

Comment: @user2357112 both of these only need to fully exhausted one iterator, but the `(0, 2)` transposition needs to fully exhaust two iterators I just found that a little unexpected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

```
def transpose_(it_it_it):
    return zip(*map(zip, *it_it_it))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TVBBjsIwDLznFRYnJ8pWbOGAkPqL3hCqXJFCJJpmU_dQEC_ZSy-7f-IdfIB02VZYPljWzHg837--51PjhuGn4-pjc3_Y2jeBwXW174U4mAo4kGt905oCLRd_LbcCYgXDXXBwsR5VTR7joEHNICkEQfaSSiiqHA2uVKrWMgmmPZE3iCsNqYZ1xJYRSgk3Z9syjtR85s4OkDRgqj_1ciSMgJ16s1fKvfDBOsZqcZ3OBuoL89XRGSnX8LbFMpcyuy3k6_X_BKYkng)

### Derivation

My first version was this, and then I just minified it. I first swap the outer two dimensions, then the inner two, then the outer two again. Using your ways of doing that. Note the variable names, they reflect the dimensions / swaps:

```
def transpose_(xyz):
    yxz = zip(*xyz)
    yzx = map(lambda xz: zip(*xz), yxz)
    zyx = zip(*yzx)
    return zyx
```

### Iteration / exhaustion visualization

For visualization, I turned the lists of the 3D input into iterators that report when they've been exhausted, and iterate the transposed data, printing its structure and values. We can see the outer two dimensions get exhausted up-front, and the innermost dimension is exhausted only at the end:

```
X-iterator exhausted
Y-iterator exhausted
Y-iterator exhausted
Y-iterator exhausted
[
  (
    0
    8
    16
  )
  (
    4
    12
    20
  )
]
[
  (
    1
    9
    17
  )
  (
    5
    13
    21
  )
]
[
  (
    2
    10
    18
  )
  (
    6
    14
    22
  )
]
[
  (
    3
    11
    19
  )
  (
    7
    15
    23
  )
]
Z-iterator exhausted
Z-iterator exhausted
Z-iterator exhausted
Z-iterator exhausted
Z-iterator exhausted
Z-iterator exhausted
```

Code:

```py
import numpy

def transpose_(it_it_it):
    return zip(*map(zip, *it_it_it))

# Versions of zip and map that exhaust all inputs
_zip = zip
def zip(*its):
    yield from _zip(*its)
    for it in its[1:]:
        next(it, None)
_map = map
def map(f, *its):
    yield from _map(f, *its)
    for it in its[1:]:
        next(it, None)

# Iterators that report when they've been exhausted
def X(it):
    yield from map(Y, it)
    print('X-iterator exhausted')
def Y(it):
    yield from map(Z, it)
    print('Y-iterator exhausted')
def Z(it):
    yield from it
    print('Z-iterator exhausted')

# Test data
a = numpy.arange(3*2*4).reshape((3, 2, 4))
b = X(a.tolist())

# Iterate the transposed data
zyx = transpose_(b)
for yx in zyx:
    print('[')
    for x in yx:
        print('  (')
        for value in x:
            print('   ', value)
        print('  )')
    print(']')
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=lVNBbtswEDz0xlcskINIQzHQJIfCQB7QS05FYTsIBBpaVQRkkiBXqZWv9JJL-6i-pktKthXEOZQQBIk7OzPcXf764wdqnX19_d1Tc_3l76fW7L0LBLbf-0GIGhugoG30LmIlDVX5USsBvAJSHyy8GC8Xe-0lf5SwOIGUEFfwHUM0zkZwTQKCtjUwFqjVBHhodR8JdNeBsb6nKKoEuk_QLJ65DcVJcTDY1dAEt4fqFMqRxgUwxCz8jo-fV09jQloWD8TWS3hwFpWokvx9MpEVkvEm274kMo_-pw4f_ith0ORCHI8bMNf2Z4uWN3AonhF2yD9THbDOjtbyVOGZleRkU7Lq6MMHY0kW62szaZxJCpVpNh_SbN_RbD6m2V6kMTRP315O5wp8Q25vrUkLzTXPU7XUPFA_UN4ubhZ3ahkwttqjlLcl3JRwx2OzY-ha6iW5zkSSalZLTIU7j2Q9cr8MB06ZDepOidQo3uZGcXQ1d_tYnFuZAcf4DAMgJ9QR-ay7HhN6Bn6TAEU5gtR7MlW8KfdTocYLN9274_37Bw)

### Benchmark

Time and memory of creating and iterating the transposed data, given data of size 100×100×100 (three attempts):

```
317 ms  845540 bytes  transpose_Tom
117 ms  825400 bytes  transpose_Kelly

351 ms  840144 bytes  transpose_Tom
127 ms  824984 bytes  transpose_Kelly

324 ms  844120 bytes  transpose_Tom
116 ms  824984 bytes  transpose_Kelly
```

Code:

```py
import numpy
import tracemalloc as tm
from timeit import repeat
import itertools

def transpose_Tom(it_it_it):
    blocks = [[iter(it) for it in it_it] for it_it in it_it_it]
    it = iter(itertools.cycle(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(*blocks))))
    while True:
        try:
            yield [[next(next(it)) for _ in range(len(blocks))]
                                   for _ in range(len(blocks[0]))]
        except StopIteration:
            break

def transpose_Kelly(it_it_it):
    return zip(*map(zip, *it_it_it))

def iterate(iii):
    for ii in iii:
        for i in ii:
            for _ in i:
                pass
n = 100
a = numpy.arange(n**3).reshape((n, n, n))
b = a.tolist()

for _ in range(3):
    for func in transpose_Tom, transpose_Kelly:

        tm.start()
        iterate(func(b))
        zyx = func(b)
        memory = tm.get_traced_memory()[1]
        tm.stop()

        time = min(repeat(lambda: iterate(func(b)), number=1))
        
        print(f'{round(time*1e3)} ms ', memory, 'bytes ', func.__name__)
    print()
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dVQ7jtswEG1S6Qip2JkSFMGGm8CADxCkzHaGQVDyaE0sfyBHiLVBTpJmm-RQOU34kWVbwQ4ESXzDeXx8_Pz6Y0c8G_329nvA_tPnvx8-CmWNQ6IHZcdiaqDjHSgupekI9wRV0TujCAoFAsnUyYEFjtcSgeDQGOmL4gR9ZNDeGg_sySgqkKWn3BUkRBt4XzzZk8MhloV0SXrjSOTWJPU8TgC7wyKc6gO2J1PlNGrTjZ2E-_aZC91E2SyCvA3ZV2FplQcvQySu72chgTy5AbK2GOjGWyPGKECegloNF6TpFSRnzSzKC5N9BipB0yv78aH-nXi3_rA-3lPApQOL5Bsa-yXOBYXRjwJbB_xl6fxXkHJceu8AB6dJskJxGz2pSTV3KjNJsgyDn0JMdWk5RFoLIW6DJzijj4rmuS3wGJZ7X-iwhpv1uuDhmzZfw7MNuqq2ZePAn7kFSnVN4hOUtaEnb9BI4ZEGoQv7tndK-0F3MfOwDeulN7vituSq8chd5L1CVw8iF23LW-J1vAQlEzyjCpRxY0gEqmdAls7QiWWYlofN8XEwY-McZigcrVCrhKb5XFHJVXviu_9k1NGtFtx-cydp_rFOaKT96oczgz7RSFttYFv-JMqTVT2prMmqHRESEnkbxjRXwFhmzCRlviKmm-J6Y_wD)

Comment: Swap the second and third layer, then swap the first and second. Clean. (The materialization is still there under the hood in the `*` unpackings, of course - can't get around that.)

Comment: ...wait, no, you're shuffling the first layer down to the end, then swapping the first two layers. `map(zip, *it_it_it)` is confusing.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, three swaps. The variable names are intended to reflect them.

Comment: @user2357112 Added a visualization now, which shows that early exhaustion of the outer two layers.

Comment: I get the derivation, `transpose(0,2)` can be implemented with three transposes i.e. three `zips`. But you final answer is correct but has only two `zips`. Oh I guess the variadic map acts like a `zip`

Comment: I thought the three transpositions wouldn't be as fast as implementing it directly, but I suspect you implementation will be faster than mine. I guess I'll have perf test them to find out

Comment: @TomHuntington Mine seems ~3x as fast as yours (tested on data size 100×100×100).

Comment: Can you share that code? If you still have it https://topaz.github.io/paste/

Comment: @TomHuntington See the added benchmark section for results and code.

Comment: @TomHuntington On 50×50×50, mine seems ~6x as fast as yours. I can't test much larger than 100×100×100 myself at the moment. Can you?

Comment: `n=500` 83056 ms  20528440 bytes  transpose_Tom | 64966 ms  20120600 bytes  transpose_Kelly. So ~1.3x times faster. I'm running wsl and get Killed for `n=1000` sorry

Comment: @TomHuntington I guess the large memory usage makes accesses slower on average, hurting both solutions equally, so their speeds converge. I tried `b = [[[0] * n] * n] * n` (no `a` needed), which takes very little memory, and there mine was about ~7x faster for n=200. I think my three transposals are really more like one, actual-work-wise. If I explicitly moved the n³ elements three times, that would be 3n³ amount of work. But I dont. The two transposals of the two outer dimensions just operate on the outer two dimensions, which is 2n² work. So n³+2n² total. At least that's how I think of it.

Comment: @TomHuntington Or in terms of my zips and map: I produce one outer zip iterator, one map iterator, and n inner zip iterators. The n inner zip iterators are the ones who actually process the third dimension, each producing n n-tuples. Together, they do n³ work. The map gets n iterables with n elements each, and feeds these n² elements to the n inner zips. Thus the map iterator does n² work. The outer zip receives the n zip iterators and iterates through them, producing n n-tuples (of n-tuples, but it doesn't look into them). So the outer zip iterator also only does n² work. Total work: n³+2n².

Comment: @TomHuntington Let me put it yet another way: I don't do 3 transposes. I do a whopping n+2 transposes. A transpose by zip or map is really just two-dimensional. With `zip(*foo)`, the `foo` is an "iterable of iterables of `bar`". It doesn't matter what `bar` is. An iterable, a number, something else... doesn't matter. The zip just treats it as any object, doesn't look into it, just puts it into its result tuples. So every transpose is only n² work. Now... We've been thinking of the `map(lambda xz: zip(*xz), yxz)` as 1 transpose of the inner two dimensions. But that's only the "logical" ..

Comment: .... view. In reality, implementation-wise, work-wise, that's n zips. Each doing a transpose. So n transposes. Not just 1. Together with my `zip(*xyz)` and my `zip(*yzx)`, it's overall n+2 transposes, each doing n² work. So (n+2)n² = n³+2n² total work for the n+2 transposes. Barely any more than the n³ work that needs to be done by *any* solution (since there are n³ base elements to iterate over in the whole 3D strucure). My oneliner solution equally does n+2 transposals for (n+2)n² work, just replaces one zip transpose with one map transpose

Comment: okay so `transpose(1,2)` is actually `transpose(0, 1)` `n` times. I just counted it as one

Comment: @TomHuntington Yes, I thought of it as one, too, and I still do. I think it's more useful for understanding the big picture. Without thinking of it that way, I might not have come up with my solution. When I saw your question, at first I tried to think through how the transposed iteration would proceed, and what iterators I'd have to build. But after a few minutes, I was like "Screw this, let's just do three dimension swaps". So the low-level thinking was difficult, but the big picture thinking made the task easy.

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools

def transpose_(it_it_it):
    blocks = [[iter(it) for it in it_it] for it_it in it_it_it]
    it = iter(itertools.cycle(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(*blocks))))
    while True:
        try:
            yield [[next(next(it)) for _ in range(len(blocks))]
                                   for _ in range(len(blocks[0]))]
        except StopIteration:
            break
```

Here's the [code](https://topaz.github.io/paste/#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) to test it

Comment: `cycle` already returns an iterator, you don't need to call `iter` on it.

Comment: [Changed a few things](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XZJBTsMwEEUlljnFqCu7MlWdtrRF6h7WdGdFkZM6xGoaG8cVDYiTsOkGDsVpGCelFEZJFP-8zJ-x5_3Ttr409fH4sffF9eLr6q5wZgfaK-eNqRrQO2uch7yUumaQt3mlopNW73e2jaKNKsA7WTfWNCol2qfdRW8jwMgqk28bWEGlG0920pLwwuCM0Q7THpEue8cEf9abjkJBaRBkhl9ftCXDPimlp5-fS10pWLu96j1DeNf-LkK0WlUbEKJWB0-6RzCHwjhIQdenQpP_ghgnyTmPOuTKenjwxt6Hgrw29V-XzCm5jSKJ3XTbM5K4M4-KTIbxcEpHTjWltIqQCYOYwRQbyBAVQowZ8E6bJAzElMGMwQ2DeRKWYsFgiUCAeBA4ghxzcAT5rGc44nyON8J8GaQY-ThkRTqeJNhIJNfnys5nRiQDEjPOxqGcAIjhxYFmNIms07UnxeD1pykn21Q97WVF5JrBhUqyNaWrtwHtB-o0Vz_z9Q0), still really your way.

Comment: [Changed some more](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZJNboMwEIWlLjnFqCuD3CgmSfMjRV13XXYIRYaYYoVg1xg1tOpJusmmPVRP0zHkt7VgwePzm-fxfH7r1haq2u-_GpvfzX5uHnKjtiCtMFapsga51cpYyAouKwpZm5XCO2hVs9Wt561FDtbwqtaqFisi7ap7_IUHuNJSZZsalhDHwZZr4pwp9ETSEeeVK9P_AVnBm9QkOJn16GshSwGRacTitNWadnHl00pRrrFcJXYWy_kHW-fZef2t-r90n_nMiV0mtIUnq_QjxudWquq6ZmoE33gex3N2XRlwbMizIKMgDMb-wIi64FoQMqIQUhj7vpd2LYmHFFinjRIK8ZjChMI9hWniPuMZhTkCDmJOYAgy9GAIsknPMMTZFF-E2dxJIfKhc0U6HCVJgsGiU7LTVRFOgYSU0aGL44A4uLjHFHuujawsyW_fj4cyvF2Jl4aXhEcULlSSRr6__Lj1-zk6jNNxrH4B).

Comment: @KellyBundy thanks for these tips, and you answer. I didn't expect 3 transposes to be the fastest solution (your derivation code is only slightly slower), the whole point of this was to try to beat 3 transposes. Now to port this to c++

Answer (score 1):

You can't really avoid the materialization you're trying to avoid.

Consider iterating over the transposed result you want:

```
for iter1 in transpose_layers_0_and_2(iterator):
    for iter2 in iter1:
        for iter3 in iter2:
            pass
```

At the end of the first iteration of the outer loop, you've accessed every element of every sub-sub-iterator of the first sub-iterator of `transpose_layers_0_and_2(iterator)`.

In the original pre-transpose iterator, these elements come from the *first* element of every sub-sub-iterator of the original `iterator`.

That means that by the time the first iteration of the outer loop is complete, you *must* have materialized the entire first two layers of the original iterator to produce every sub-sub-iterator. There's no way around it. Plus, you've only used one element of each sub-sub-iterator, so you still have to retain all those sub-sub-iterators in memory to produce the remaining elements. You can't discard them yet.

Comment: I had already realized this, but probably didn't write up the question really well. I was asking if there is a more elegant python solution than my answer. The whole intertwining and then chunking ended up a little janky. I suppose I was also wondering if this was the best strategy