# Is there a name for `[[[(a, b, ..., z)]]]` -> `([[[a]]], [[[b]]], ..., ([[[z]]]))`?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Is there a name for this operation? (Also is there a name these functions whose type signature can have only one possible/natural "instantiation"?)

How is this function typically implemented? Iterating `tuple_dimension` times like this?

```hs
insideout = map (map (map fst)) &&& map (map (map snd))
```

Is the a naming convention?

To be clear, for the homogenous case this is tensor permutation:

```py
>>> images.shape
(32, 30, 40, 3)

# stack along first (batch) axis, output is a single array
>>> rearrange(images, 'b h w c -> b h w c').shape
(32, 30, 40, 3)

# reordered axes to "b c h w" format for deep learning
>>> rearrange(images, 'b h w c -> b c h w').shape
(32, 3, 30, 40)
```

https://einops.rocks/api/rearrange/

Comment: Looks like so "zip" operation.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem `zip` only transposes dimensions `0` and `1`, you can use `map` and `zip` to transpose adjacent dimensions. You can combine these to achieve arbitrary permutations https://stackoverflow.com/a/75449063/11998382

Comment: The title of this question does not make sense to me. It would also help me to see example inputs and outputs.

Comment: @Noughtmare `unzip` for the functor `Compose [] (Compose [] [])` seems like the answer I wanted

Comment: sorry, I guess the title didn't make sense

Comment: Ah, I saw that your insideout function is not that. And indeed the type of that is probably not what you expect it to be. Instead I think you meant `insideout t = (map (map (map fst)) t, map (map (map snd)) t)` which is different in important ways. I removed my earlier comment because this confused me.

Comment: Regarding functions with only one possible implementation: This is the result of something called "parametricity". Sometimes it is not only *one* implementation, but the collection of possible implementations is very restricted. This fact is expressed by a "free theorem." Every parametrically polymorphic function has an associated free theorem. Some resources: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5369065/2476735), [2](https://well-typed.com/blog/2015/05/parametricity/), [3](https://people.mpi-sws.org/~dreyer/tor/papers/wadler.pdf), [4](https://people.mpi-sws.org/~dreyer/tor/papers/reynolds.pdf)

Comment: I got ChatGPT free.5 to port `unzip` to haskell, I didn't manage. What I meant was `map (map (map fst)) &&& map (map (map snd))`

Comment: @DavidYoung I reasked the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77592808/) thanks, I realized I failed at learning haskell a while back, because I didn't realize what `forall` was actually doing, but 2 explains it quite clearly